# Migrate React Native Project for Web also using same code using React Native Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web, multi-device-hybrid-apps

My task is to add web support in existing react-native project using react -native-web package
But I am getting issues for those packages that does not have support in web like "ActionsheetIos is not exported".

If this type of component is used inside my react native code component, I can simply create new file .web.ts extension and export empty object from it.
Then error goes away, but what should I do when same error comes inside my ** node_module** folder dependencies code.

How to handle this case.

Currently , I am following CRA create react approach inside react native web...adding CRA scripts in react native code and running web from it.

Any idea how to tackle this issue and also is my approach is fine?

I checked for multiple online solutions but could not find right direction

Comment: Anyone , having input ?